# Is it better to have a single JAXBContext or separate contexts for each class?

Tags: java, jaxb, singleton

I know JAXBContext should be created only once as it's pretty expensive, but I'm curious if it's preferable to create one context for all the required classes,

```
JAXBContext newInstance(Class... classesToBeBound)
```

Or keep all the contexts in a map and create them if they haven't been created yet?

```
Map<Class, JAXBContext> map = new HashMap<>();

public JAXBContext getContext(Class clazz) {
    if (map.get(clazz) == null) {
        map.put(clazz, JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz));
    }
    return map.get(clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could never understand why people create the `JAXBContext` per class or even for several classes.

I prefer creating `JAXBContext` for a specific context path which is normally one or more packages corresponding to individual schemas I need to use. I can then use it for all classes in these packages and it also covers more complicated cases like substitution groups.

So:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo:org.terra.bar");
```

If I were to make it class-based, then I'd create one `JAXBContext` per package. And also consider multi-threaded access so that no two threads would create two `JAXBContexts` in parallel.